# How to analyze a set of motivations ordered by priority

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, survey, ranking

I need to analyze the answers of a questionnaire where participants reported a set of motivations for the adoption of a technology.

Motivations are ordered by importance and are not pre-defined.

Eg.

- participant 1: 1) M1, 2) M2, 3) M3
- participant 2: 1) M4, 2) M1, 3) M2, 4) M5
- participant 3: 1) M2, 2) M2, 3) M4

We have a total of 22 participants, that proposed a total of 10 motivations (several participants reported a similar set of motivations but ranked in a different order)

Which kind of analysis can I perform?